# Converting a greyscale image to a single solid colour with Photoshop, while preserving transparency

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, images

I have a grey scale image, with transparency. How can I convert this to one solid specific color, and preserve its edges/transparency?

As an example of what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

Comment: Converting the picture to RGB (Image->Mode) then using a Hue/Sturation layer with "Colorize" checked *should* do it. Can you try that and edit your question if it doesn't work? (There *are* other ways. In Photoshop, there are *always* other ways.)

Comment: I need to set the solid colour exactly (with a hex value). I cant just get it close enough by eye by tweaking these levels.

Comment: This is very hard to answer when you want to use an exact value with transparency. Is it a solid black irregular shape? Or are there different shades of grey? If there's different shades of grey than which part needs to be the exact hex value - the black? The white? The midtones?

Comment: The image has different colours and variable transparency. I need to make a solid colour out of any part of the original image that has a solid colour. I want the semi transparent parts to be ignored for this.

Comment: Ctrl/Cmd + Click on the image box in the layer panel. Then create a new layer. Then fill with your desired HEX value.

Comment: Example images of what you're starting with and the result you want to achieve are always helpful for questions like these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly:

First, make sure that you are in RGB mode. (image > mode)

Right-click the layer you want to convert to a solid color, and click blending options.

In this window, go to the color overlay tab on the left, and in the right pane choose a color.

Looks like this. (image from [here](http://wonderlandstockx.deviantart.com/art/free-cutout-spider-png-on-transparent-background-379325888/))

[image]

Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 3):

Select All and Copy (<kbd>cmd/ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>cmd/ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) and then create a new fill layer (`Layer > New Fill Layer > Solid Color`). Click ok on the first dialogue box and then select a color.
Now your layer panel should look like this:

[image]

Now <kbd>alt</kbd>-Click on the `Layer Mask` of your fill layer (the white box next to the layer thumbnail). Now you can directly edit the layer mask: Just `Paste` the b/w-image you copied before in the now empty, white workspace (<kbd>cmd/ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) and invert the “colors” by pressing <kbd>cmd/ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.

[image]

You can leave the layer mask mode simply by clicking anywhere in the layers panel. 
Now you just have to delete your original black and white layer and you’re done.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer however I need a solid fill eg something like this: http://www.clker.com/cliparts/m/i/f/x/A/t/fish-outline-black-filled.svg

Comment: @jdln Oh sorry, I misunderstood. You should add this image to your question, so other people who have the same problem, immediately know if they are looking at the right question.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to get that nice, silhouette effect. How about using color overlays since parts of the image already has transparency?

Layer> layer style> color overlay

Answer (score 0):

My way of dealing with this (i have to do it a lot actually), is i copy the layer i want to convert into a new temporary grayscale document, then convert it to a monotone using the specific hex number. then plop it back into the orig file, and just hide the orig layer (incase i need to go back for some reason, or change the color). Maybe it seems a bit weird of a way to do it, i just like treating it like im using a photocopier as opposed to all that layer jockeying.. but to each their own.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the photo to appear as dark on a colored background, you can apply the same steps, but use black as overlay color. Then add a new color fill layer beneath it with the desired background color.